# Conditionally make Nginx redirects to index.html

Tags: redirect, nginx, query-string

how to redirect to `index.html` for all the url except when the url has one particular QueryString?

For example:

Redirect all other url with Query strings to `index.html` except when it has `ngsw-cache-bust`

```
 example.com/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.24039143891136616
```

i tried the following code

```
    server {
      index index.html;
      root /dist;
      listen 80;
      location / {
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
      }
  }
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like this

```
 server {
      index index.html;
      root /dist;
      listen 80;
      location / {
        if($arg_ngsw-cache-bust == "") {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html last;
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: why we rewrite instead of sending file as ngsw.json ?

Comment: If the query parameter `ngsw-cache-bust` is missing or has an empty value - then we make an internal redirect to `index.html`. But if the query parameter is not empty - then we simply try to return the corresponding file (or a 404 error if the file is missing). Was not this the requested behavior?

Comment: yeah exactly ...but why do we use rewrite ?

Comment: To save a few round trips - if you return 301 this will force the browser to issue another HTTP request. It is faster and simpler if you just send the file on the first request.